# What happens if one multiplies two elements belonging to two different groups?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

What happens if one multiplies two elements belonging to two different groups? Where does the result lie? Let's say that $a \in \mathbb{Z/pZ}$ and $b \in \mathbb{Z/p^2Z}$, then where does $a \cdot b$ belong?

Comment: By definition the group operation is defined only for two elements in the same group. So you can't multiply two elements from different groups, unless you can somehow put them together in a bigger group, e.g. the direct product of them. In your context, it maybe the case that $\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}_p/p^2 \mathbb{Z}_p$ is regarded as a $\mathbb{Z}_p$-module

Comment: In general you can't multiply two elements from different groups, because group multiplication is only defined for two elements of the group. If both your groups, call them H and K, sit inside some common group G, then you could multiply an element of H by one of K _within G_, but you should say that this is what you are doing.

Comment: @aPaulT Is there a common group in my case?

Comment: Without getting bogged down in technical details, no there isn't one directly, but there could be ways of thinking about your groups in which they can be seen as 'living' inside a common object, as Sanches mentions.

Comment: I've seen group theorists denote by $\mathbb{Z}_p$ the cyclic group of order $p$, and I've seen number theorists denote by $\mathbb{Z}_p$ the ring of $p$-adic integers. Could you clarify which one you mean?

Comment: @DanShved the first option: the cyclic group of order $p$

Comment: @curious Anyway, the previous comments still stand. The expression $a\cdot b$ is meaningless unless you yourself specify what you mean. You could mean that $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is regarded as a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$, in which case $a \cdot b$ is just an element of $\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$. Or you can look at $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ as a module over the ring $\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$, in which case $a \cdot b$ is an element of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. It could also be something else entirely.

Comment: Given that $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$ as abelian groups are usually written additively, and there is a dot in $a \cdot b$, I would say it is likely that $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is regarded as a module over ring $\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$, so the result is in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. But there's no way to be sure without some context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Motto: One cannot add apples and oranges, except if one considers them all as fruits.

In other words, given two groups $(G,\ast)$ and $(H,\circ)$, there is no way to compose $g$ in $G$ and $h$ in $H$ in general. To begin with, should we consider $g\ast h$ or $g\circ h$? Neither, since $g\ast h$ is not defined if $h$ is not in $G$ and $g\circ h$ is not defined if $g$ is not in $H$.

On the other hand, if there exists a third group $(K,\cdot)$ containing $(G,\ast)$ and $(H,\circ)$ as subgroups, then $g\cdot h$ makes sense as an element of $K$.

This requires to specify $(K,\cdot)$ since $(G,\ast)$ and $(H,\circ)$ could also be subgroups of another group $(L,\odot)$ and one would need to know whether $g$ and $h$ are composed using the composition law $\cdot$ of $K$ or the composition law $\odot$ of $L$.

Such a group $(K,\cdot)$ always exists, an example being the product group defined by $K=G\times H$ and the composition law $(g,h)\cdot(g',h')=(g\ast g',h\circ h')$. Then $K$ contains $G$ and $H$ in the sense that there exist canonical injective morphisms $a:G\to K$ and $b:H\to K$, for example, $a:g\mapsto(g,e_H)$ and $b:h\mapsto(e_G,h)$. Then, the composition of $g$ in $G$ and $h$ in $H$ is $a(g)\cdot b(h)$, which, in our example, is simply the pair $(g,h)$.

If one reads the groups in the example of the question as being the additive groups $(G,\ast)=(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z,+)$ and $(H,\circ)=(\mathbb Z/p^2\mathbb Z,+)$, still another construction can be used. Consider $(K,\cdot)=(\mathbb Z/p^2\mathbb Z,+)$ and the morphisms $a:\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z/p^2\mathbb Z$, $i\mapsto pi$, and $b:\mathbb Z/p^2\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z/p^2\mathbb Z$, $j\mapsto j$. Then the composition law in $\mathbb Z/p^2\mathbb Z$ of some $i$ in $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ and some $j$ in $\mathbb Z/p^2\mathbb Z$ produces 
$$
a(i)+b(j)=pi+j,
$$ 
in $\mathbb Z/p^2\mathbb Z$. This represents the first group $(G,\ast)=(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z,+)$ as a subgroup of the second group $(H,\circ)=(\mathbb Z/p^2\mathbb Z,+)$ and uses the composition law of $H$.